# OpenVPN load balancing

Tags: vpn, openvpn, load-balancing

The question is in general about the best practices. VPN network has to manage about a thousand of simultaneous connections, so there is a problem in load balancing over several OpenVPN servers.

First question is the method itself:

1. [IPVS](http://techtots.blogspot.ru/2010/01/load-balancing-openvpn-connections-via.html)
2. Standard random OpenVPN balancer, as stated in its documentation

What are the advantages of these methods?

Second is the key exchange method. Rsync in crontab seems the most suitable solution for me. Is there any other good practices?